# Boolean value is not set in view, but is in controller

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, observable

In my TaskHandler module I have a `TaskOverviewController.ts`:

```
$onInit() {
    this.observeTaskUpdates();
}

private observeTaskUpdates(): void {
    showTaskDetailView$
        .subscribe(value => {
            this.showTaskDetailView = value
            console.log('value', value);
            console.log('this.showTaskDetailView', this.showTaskDetailView)
        });
}
```

This `TaskOverviewController` is linked to the `TaskOverview.html`:

```
<div id="grid-container" class="dashboard-container" ng-controller="TaskOverviewController as vm">
    ShowTaskDetailView: {{vm.showTaskDetailView}}
    <div id="main" ng-if="vm.showTaskDetailView">
        show if true
    </div>
</div>
```

On a different module `CustomerService` I have a `ActivityTimelineItemComponent.ts`:

```
public showDetailTaskView() {
    showTaskDetailView$.onNext(true)
}
```

When I trigger the `showDetailTaskView()`function on the `ActivityTimelineItem.html` I get routed to another page,

```
<div >
     <i
        ng-click="vm.showDetailTaskView()"
        ui-sref="dashboard.tasks.overview.details.information({ id: activity.task.id})"
        >reply</i
     >
</div>
```

And this is on the console:

> TaskOverviewController.ts:31 value true
>
> TaskOverviewController.ts:32 this.showTaskDetailView true
>
> TaskOverviewController.ts:31 value true
>
> TaskOverviewController.ts:32 this.showTaskDetailView true

But the `#main` element is  not visible in the DOM. And the `ShowTaskDetailView: {{vm.ShowTaskDetailView}}` is also not showing the controllers set value.

I've tried wrapping the `.subscribe` in the `TaskOverviewController` in a timeout, but that didn't work either. So why is my controller showing that the `showTaskDetailView` value is `true` but my DOM isn't showing the `ng-if="vm.ShowTaskDetailView"`

Comment: Where is the DOM element with `ui-sref` situated in relation to the `#grid-container` element snippet you've listed? It could be that you've actually got two instances of `TaskOverviewController` active and the one used by `#grid-container` (different `this`) wasn't told about the triggering event.

Comment: @miqh hm interesting. I've updated my question to better show how everything is set up. To check this I could set a variable in the `TaskOverviewController` and increment it by 1. If they're seperate instances the count should be different. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you could try that. My suggestion is just a hunch because I can't see the full structure of all the code involved. You mention that the link trigger is in a completely different HTML template, which makes me wonder what `vm` in that case is. Probably another `TaskOverviewController` instance?

Comment: That doesn't seem the issue, I've just added a count++ to the subscribe in the controller and when I navigate from the `ActivityTimelineItem` it adds up the count that was made earlier (there are multiple ways to acces the controller). I think the issue is the async nature of the observable.

Comment: Ah, okay. Perhaps the `onNext` handler doesn't trigger within AngularJS' context when the link is triggered and thus you're not seeing the changes in the DOM. Maybe try a `scope.$apply()` inside the variable update?

Comment: I've added `this.$scope.$apply();` to the `showDetailsItemView()` function. But it's giving a error:

`[$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress at TaskOverviewController.cXSr.TaskOverviewController.observeTaskUpdates`